# Как инициализировать свойства типа Объект в trait'ах PHP или существует ли возможность регистрации нескольких __construct методов в очередь?

Tags: php, ооп, классы, методы

Мне нужно инициализировать свойство трейта как экземпляр соседнего класса.

```
trait FilterTrait {
    protected $_filter = new Filter(); // Нельзя использовать как дефолтное значение

    public function __construct () { // Перезапишется в используемом классе
        $this->_filter = new Filter();
    }

    public function SetFilter ($arFilter) {
        $this->_filter->Set($arFilter);
    }

    public function CleanFilter () {
        $this->_filter->CLean();
    }

    public function GetFilter () {
        return $this->_filter->Get();
    }
    ...
}
```

Не хочу, чтобы дочерний класс помогал в работе используемого трейта, и вообще знал что-то об его устройстве, вот так:

```
class Select extends Query {
    use TablesListTrait,
        FieldsListTrait,
        FilterTrait,
        HavingTrait,
        SortTrait,
        LimitTrait,
        GroupTrait;

    function __construct () {
        $this->_tablesList = new TablesList();
        $this->_fieldsList = new FieldsList();
        $this->_filter = new Filter();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

И инициализировать при каждом вызове метода тоже не хочу

```
trait FilterTrait {
    protected $_filter;

    public function InitializeFilter () {
        if (is_null($this->_filter)) {
            $this->_filter = new Filter();
        }
    }

    public function SetFilter ($arFilter) {
        $this->InitializeFilter();
        $this->_filter->Set($arFilter);
    }

    public function CleanFilter () {
        $this->InitializeFilter();
        $this->_filter->CLean();
    }

    public function GetFilter () {
        $this->InitializeFilter();
        return $this->_filter->Get();
    }
}
```

Можно, конечно, замутить перезагрузку методов, но это не сильно лучше.

Нашел информацию о том, что в версии 5.6 вот такое написание поддерживается

```
class Foo {
    protected $bar = new Baz();
}
```

не проверял, но все-таки большинство хостингов на данный момент стоят на 5.3 - 5.4, и использовать эти фишки пока сложно. К тому же хочу еще реализовать регистрацию мнемоник для вызова методов трейта из параметров, передающихся в дочерние классы. Если бы существовал какой-нибудь магический метод, регистрирующий несколько `__construct` функций, мне бы это помогло:

```
trait Actions {
    protected $_arActions = array();

    public function RegisterActions ($arActions) {
        $this->_arActions = array_merge($this->_arActions, $arActions);
    }

    public function ResetParameters ($arParameters) {
        foreach ($arParameters as $mnemonic => $actionParameters) {
            if (isset($this->_arActions[$mnemonic])) {
                $action = $this->_arActions[$mnemonic];
                $this->$action($actionParameters);
            }
        }
    }
}

trait FilterTrait {
    use Actions;

    public function __onUse () {
        $arActions = array(
            "filter" => "SetFilter"
        );
        $this->RegisterActions($arActions);
    }

    public function SetFilter ($arFilter) {...}
}

class Select extends Query {
    use TablesListTrait,
        FieldsListTrait,
        FilterTrait,
        HavingTrait,
        SortTrait,
        LimitTrait,
        GroupTrait;

    public function __construct ($arParams) {
        $this->ResetParameters($arParams);
    }
}

...
$arSelectParams = array(
    "table" => "products",
    "fields" => array(
        "id",
        "name",
        "price"
    ),
    "filter" => array(
        "name" => "%iphone%",
        "<=price" => 15000
    ),
    "sort" => array(
        "price" => "asc"
    )
);
$query = new Select($arSelectParams);
```

Есть какой-нибудь вариант сделать что-то подобное сейчас или, если нет, ожидается ли концепция подобного в будущем, где-нибудь в седьмой версии?

Comment: Вот поэтому множественное наследование и не используют. Трейты как миксины не имеют права на инциализацию, потому что только приносят дополнительный функционал и не принимают участия в конструировании объекта. Если вам нужна реализация множества классов с некоторым функционалом и одинаковым внешним доступом, то стоит использовать просто массив реализаций одного интерфейса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная идея трейтов состоит в том, чтобы дать возможность *примешивать* некоторое поведение к классу. Сам по себе трейт не является полноценной сущностью, поэтому использование `__construct` в нем лишено смысла с точки зрения строгого Объектно-Ориентированного Подхода.

То, что вы хотите сделать скорее похоже не множественное наследование, чем на примеси. И да, в PHP нет множественного наследования.

Если говорить о инициализации свойств, то я бы посоветовал вам инициализировать поля трейтов только тогда, когда это нужно. В вопросе вы приводите кусок кода, с инициализацией свойства в каждом методе, добавляя:

> И инициализировать при каждом вызове метода тоже не хочу

Проблема в том, что вы неверно реализуете инициализацию по требованию. Правильным решением было бы использовать для получения свойств геттеры/сеттеры и уже в них реализовывать логику инициализации. Например так:

```
trait FilterTrait {
    protected $_filter;

    public function setFilter ($arFilter) {
        $this->_filter = $arFilter;
    }

    public function getFilter () {
        if (is_null($this->_filter)) {
            $this->_filter = new Filter();
        }

        return $this->_filter;
    }

    public function cleanFilter () {
        $this->getFilter()->clean();
    }

    public function doSomethig() {
        $this->getFilter()->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Что касается последнего вашего примера, я бы рекомендовал использовать сеттеры для параметров запроса (фильтров, сортировок, ...) в явном виде, а не использовать магию конфигурации через конструктор. Примерно так функционирует [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) и другие аналогичные библиотеки. Вот так может выглядеть пример построения запроса:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('email = ?')
    ->setParameter(0, $user_email);
```

В этом примере используется два общеизвестных шаблона проектирования: [Builder](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) и [Fluent Interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). Думаю вам будет полезно ознакомится с этими и другими шаблонами проектирования.